# Why methods in jar can't be resolved in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am reading the book algorithm 4th edition (Sedgewick). The book has two libraries: stdlib.jar and algs4.jar. I include them both in eclipse, but it is not possible to compile the code correctly. Like the picture:
[image]

ST and StdIn are classes from algs4.jar and stdlib.jar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import those classes in your `FrequencyCounter` class.  For example:

```
import some.package.structure.ST;
import some.package.structure.StdIn;
```

If you hover over the red line under ST and StdIn, it most likely will give you an option to import them.

Comment: ST and StdIn are all in default package.

Comment: @Tian Then you'll need to make your class in the default package too unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

FrequencyCounter  must be in default package, its the only way to use those classes since they don't have packages.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two jars in project build path-

```
Goto: Project Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External JARs...
```

Then import classes from the jar and there you go..

Answer (score 0):

whiskeyspider is right. You can automatically import the classes by placing the cursor after ST and StdIn and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Another note, packages name must be lowercase, it's a bad practice to capitalize them. See java documentation :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, eclipse automatically import missing classes, unless these doesn't exist in the BuildPath.

PD: Sorry for my english